# Please explain ST_GeomFromText parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, select, postgis

I am having trouble understanding ST_GeomFromText.  It looks like there are 3 sets of 2 numbers.  Why is that?  Wouldn't coordinates just consist of a latitude and longitude?

Here is an example from http://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html:

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-71.160281 42.258729,-71.160837 42.259113,-71.161144 42.25932)');
```

Comment: I see.  I'm just wondering what each number represents.  It seems like there are too many for it to be simple coordinates.

Comment: A `LINESTRING` can have *any number* of points on it. It represents a line drawn through each point sequentially.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ST_GeomFromText()` takes a [WKT expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) of a geometry object and

> Constructs a PostGIS ST_Geometry object from the OGC Well-Known text representation.

The WKT expression in the example is a [`LINESTRING`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895372.aspx) which is

> a one-dimensional object representing a sequence of points and the line segments connecting them.

You might think a linestring would be two-dimensional, but it's not, because a line has no width or height.  (Points are 0-dimensional, polygons are 2-dimensional).

So, by definition, that would have more than one set of coordinates.  A pair of coordinates would be a `POINT`, not a linestring, and would look something like this, in conjunction with the function in question:

```
ST_GeomFromText('POINT (30 10)');
```

You may want to read up on some GIS fundamentals:

http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~mschneid/Service/Tutorials/TutorialSDT.pdf - excellent tutorial
http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/orm - OGC Reference Model

Comment: so each pair of numbers in the line string or polygon represents a point?

Comment: Yes, but with a qualification: in a linestring or polygon, the ordering is also significant, because the consecutive points are connected to each other, in the order stated; this, in contrast to a `MULTIPOINT` object, which is one of several primitives that defines a collection of un-ordered, un-connected (though possibly overlapping) objects.